# After upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 my webcam fails to work properly "a lot of buffers are being dropped"

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, webcam, logitech, microsoft

I just recently did a release upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. I have already made all the APT updates, upgrades and fixed the NVIDIA driver.

I have not been able to figure out the webcam though. This is a Logitech C270.

```
$ lsusb | grep "Webcam"
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
```

When in Zoom, the webcam turns its green light on, but I just see a black frame. Changing any of the preference options did nothing there.

When in Cheese, it starts, green light comes on, then I see the image moving somewhat sloppy then it starts to freeze more and more. When this happens, Cheese in terminal shows the following:

```
$ cheese 
(cheese:7231): cheese-WARNING **: 16:01:25.695: A lot of buffers are being dropped.: ../libs/gst/base/gstbasesink.c(3143): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstViewfinderBin:vf-bin/ClutterGstVideoSink:cluttergstvideosink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
```

Clearly, there is something wrong with the webcam communication or streaming. I'm quite lost here as I'm not familiar on this area. I search for similar cases here in the forums but no luck.

- My camera "is" detected, so this does not applies: [Ubuntu 22.04 has problems detecting my Logitech webcam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441327/ubuntu-22-04-has-problems-detecting-my-logitech-webcam)
- I'm not getting this error, so not sure if it applies: [webcam problems - can not save picture](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405187/webcam-problems-can-not-save-picture) while I have confirmed that it is the same version of Cheese, the problem is also in Zoom. I don't think Cheese "owns" gstreamer or the codecs, right?
- I am not using motion or fuser, not sure if any is needed: [Upgrade to 22.04 - webcam light on and not usable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423169/upgrade-to-22-04-webcam-light-on-and-not-usable)

I have also tried changing USB ports, even change to other webcams (Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000) but also see the same behavior (and they used to prior to the update).

Hopefully I can get some help from the community. Anything I can run to help with troubleshooting let me know (instructions help a bit since I'm not an expert in Linux).

Cheers!
Nestor

Comment: After further troubleshooting, scouting the web and waiting for an answer, I unfortunately had to give up. I cannot afford to have my computer without webcam. I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (downgraded) and everything is working normal now.

If anyone does have some suggestions or there is a known solution, I'd love to hear about it, as I was hoping to be using 22.04.

Comment: The only thing I can add by the way, is that with 22.04 the webcam is recognized in Cheese as only the last for characters of the ID, for example as in my description above "0825" that's all you see from the pull-down list of available webcams. Whereas in 20.04 you do see a longer "UVC:xxxxxxxx" ID.